# Must all script tags be type module when using module syntax

Tags: javascript, module

I am currently looking into converting some of my personal libraries into the module syntax for a project. This project is not using a framework, like Node.js or React. I would probably be using some of them in module syntax, and others not.

Say I have an object `CookiePicker`. `CookiePicker` was not written as a module, so it does not export any functions. `CookiePicker` does import an object, `DOMFactory`, to offload some of the work. When including `CookiePicker.js`, which only contains object/function definitions, in the HTML, it seems I have to use `type="module"`

Later in the HTML, I open a script tag to actually use the object defined in `CookiePicker.js`. But, I then get an error saying that my object is not defined. If I add `type="module"` to this script tag, the code executes as expected, after I import the `CookiePicker` object.

**Is it not possible to chain module syntax with plain JS syntax?**

#### Relevant Code

**/js/modules/DOMFactory.mjs**

```
export default function DOMFactory()
{
    ...
}
```

**./CookiePicker.js**

```
import DOMFactory from '/js/Modules/DOMFactory.mjs';

function CookiePicker(arg1, arg2)
{
    ...
}
CookiePicker.prototype.init= function()
{
    ...
}
```

**./CookiePicker.html**

```
<html>
    ...
    <script type="module" src="CookiePicker.js"></script>
    ...
    <!-- ReferenceError
    <script>
        var s = new CookiePicker('selector', '');
    
        s.init();
    </script>
    -->

    <!-- Works once I add an export to the CookiePicker function -->
    <script type="module">
        import CookiePicker from './CookiePicker.js'
        var s = new CookiePicker('selector', '');
    
        s.init();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Say I have an object CookiePicker. CookiePicker was not written as a module, so it does not export any functions.

It uses `import`, so it *has* been written as a module - only modules can use the `import` (or `export`) keyword. So, you're right when you say:

> When including CookiePicker.js, which only contains object/function definitions, in the HTML, it seems I have to use type="module"

> Is it not possible to chain module syntax with plain JS syntax?

Not easily. Modules generally run asynchronously, and they purposefully do not pollute the global object, so hooking into them from an external non-module script isn't all that natural.

While you *could* do something like add an event listener for the event when the module fully loads, and have the outermost module trigger that listener, it's ugly and isn't really the way to use modules. The *right* way to do this would be to, since modules are involved, make *everything* a module, per your

```
<!-- Works once I add an export to the CookiePicker function -->
```

Doing that is just fine, and would probably be the best way to do it.